# How to change the NuGet-package reference in a Visual Studio project to use Nuget.config

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, nuget

I have a Visual Studio project file with the extension .csproj. Inside it are references like this:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props"....
```

I have now made a NuGet.config file in the parent folder of from the solution folder. And I removed the local "packages" folder. In the new nuget.config I set up a common location for storing packages.

nuget.config:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <config>
        <add key="repositoryPath" value="D:\Data\NuGet" />
    </config>
    <packageRestore>
        <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    </packageRestore>
</configuration>
```

When I building I now get this error:

> This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information... 
>   The missing file is ..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props.

How can I solve this?

If I manually have to replace the (Import Project="..\packages...) elements in the project file, what should I change it to, so that it follows the configuration from the Nuget.config?

Comment: What did your new `nuget.config` file do? Did it change the address of the local nuget installation? Or Could you please share it with us?

Comment: I added the content of the new nuget.config file to my question now. It is basically just setting a path for where to store all the packages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I manually have to replace the (Import Project="..\packages...)
>   elements in the project file, what should I change it to, so that it
>   follows the configuration from the Nuget.config?

Since you use the new `nuget.config` file which changed the path of the local nuget reference(like this `<add key="repositoryPath" value="xxxxxx" />`).

And **Restore** will only restore the missing nuget packages but will not change to use the new nuget package location in `xxx.csproj`.

So you can follow my steps to resolve the issue:

**Solution**

**1)** Tools-->Nuget Package Manager-->Package Manager Console-->

type `Update-Package -reinstall` to reinstall these packages to reference the new right path.

**2)** enter the `xxxx.csproj` file, delete these duplicate, old `import` info like these:

```
 <Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props" Condition="Exists('..\..\..\..\..\..\installed_packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" />

 <Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
```

**3)** Then rebuild your project  and will solve this issue.

**Update 1**

The new `Nuget.config` file will specify that the newly installed nuget packages use the new reference address, but for previously installed nuget packages, the reference address in the `xxx.csporj` file will remain the old address. The **Restore** procedure only restores the nuget package under the new path, but it does not make any changes to the nuget reference in `xxx.csproj` file, so it can only be reinstalled.

**Besides**, the import node is created by `Microsoft.Net.Compilers` props file from the `build` folder in the `microsoft.net.compilers`nuget package. And [it is a nuget mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package#include-msbuild-props-and-targets-in-a-package) which can do some operation in `xxx.csproj` file when you install the nuget package.

**However**, this file is also special and when you change the nuget reference path. 
**Because** nuget enabled the new address mechanism, during the uninstallation process, the old address of `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props` is still not recognized, so it cannot be uninstalled. **In fact**, when you execute the reinstall nuget package, a new address has been created in the `xxx.csproj` file. See this:

[image]

So you should just delete duplicate files from the old address.

Comment: I could see that all the packages where downloaded to the new location. But it's only the Import-elements in the projects that doesn't seem to be updated to reflect the correct location.

Comment: This Import-element file is special and when you use the new nuget address mechanism from `Nuget.config` file, nuget won't recognize the old path of `Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props` from installed nuget package `Microsoft.Net.Compilers`. So the uninstallation process will not delete it at the same time. However, during the reinstallation process, it also create the new Import-element which uses the new right path. You should only delete the duplicate file. Also, I've updated my answer and you can check it and if it does help you understand and handle this issue, you can consider accepting it.

Answer (score 0):

[Visual Studio option to change the Nuget Package References](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UGAJu.png)

- In Visual Studio Tools=> Nuget Package Manager => Package Sources.
- You can change the package sources here.